# Как склоняется название Манжерок?

Tags: склонение

На Алтае есть озеро Манжерок. Подскажите, как оно правильно склоняется?
Например: был на Манжерке или был на Манжероке?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **был на Манжероке**, например: После двух недель спокойной жизни **в Манжероке** предисполкома организовал вторую поездку на машинах, в этот раз вверх по р. [В. А. Обручев. Мои путешествия по Сибири (1948)]

**В современных текстах** также практически везде используется форма "на/о/в Манжероке", например: Манжерок - популярное направление отдыха среди туристов. Здесь представлена вся информация **о Манжероке**: фотографии, погода, интересные места и факты.

А вот такая запись **неверна**: Погода **в Манжерке** на 10 дней подробно.

**Пояснение**

Чередование беглых гласных с нулем происходит во многих словах, в том числе на ОК (**в суффиксе или в основе**), **но не всегда**: восток, ездок, знаток, игрок, пророк, урок и т.д.

**Поэтому вряд ли можно ожидать наличие такого чередования в топонимах,** которые обычно стремятся сохранить точность названия при склонении.

Answer (score 0):

У меня нет под рукой словаря топонимов, но и по памяти, и по логике - **на Манжероке** (с заглавной, кстати).

Здесь нет причин считать, что "ок" - суффикс, а значит и для беглости гласной оснований нет.

Вики того же мнения (хотя это и слабый аргумент, но все-таки) -

> В последние годы поймать рыбу в Манжер**о**ке проблематично — вероятно, из-за слива,